# Программа не открывается вне своей папки

Tags: c#

Я создал небольшую программу которая сравнивает числа и выводит сообщение что больше а что меньше.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "MicroGameC#";
            string a1 = "A is bigger than B.";
            string b1 = "B is bigger than A.";
            while (true)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
                Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                Console.Clear();
                try
                {
                    Console.Write("First number (A): ");
                    int a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    Console.Write("Second number (B): ");
                    int b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                    if (a > b)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(a1 + " A has a value of = " + a);
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(b1 + " B has a value of = " + b);
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                    Console.Clear();
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
                    Console.WriteLine("Incorrect input, only numbers!");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Решил отправить другу её, вынес на рабочий стол из рабочей папки (`\source\repos\ConsoleApp1\ConsoleApp1\bin\Debug\net5.0`) на рабочий стол. Но вне "рабочей папки" она не открывается, я насколько понимаю - она зависит от библиотек и необходимого ей в той папке?

`Раньше из папки Debug её можно было спокойно взять, а щас почему-то не выходит.`

Как мне "собрать" программу что бы её можно было свободно использовать вне?

Comment: Вам нужно опубликовать приложение - Build > Publish, выбрать папку, там еще есть опция сборки в 1 файл. А так, вам нужен не только exe файл, но и dll рядом с ним.

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Comment: @aepot правда я не могу найти в списке опцию "1 файл". https://i.imgur.com/C0Bdb9i.png

Comment: Целевая среда win-x64, и появится

Comment: @aepot Заработало, ещё раз огромное спасибо =).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что бы опубликовать приложение - Сборка > Опубликовать #name# - Целевой обьект - Папка. Затем в выпадающем списке выбрать в графе "Целевая среда выполнения" - win-x64

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]